# jQuery attr in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, attributes, attr

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="myPage.htm">
  <img src="anImage.jpg />
</a>
<a href="yourPage.htm">
  <img src="anotherImage.jpg />
</a>
<a href="everyonesPage.htm">
  <img src="stillAnotherImage.jpg />
</a>
```

And the following javascript (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($('img', this).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

In Firefox this alerts the src attribute of the image clicked, but in IE7 and IE6 it alerts 'undefined'. Any ideas why this is and how to return the src of the image when clicking the relevant anchor tag?

EDIT:
Sorry guys, jsFiddle example here (http://jsfiddle.net/wabqw/) with original code (yes, code above was a simplified version). Works in Chrome but no IE (firefox fails to display the images so there's nothing to click on!).

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case? It seems to work fine here in IE7 using either of `1.4.4` and `1.6`: [http://jsfiddle.net/xV82c/](http://jsfiddle.net/xV82c/) - if I keep the missing quotes as you had them, there's still an `alert`, it's just got some extra stuff. I think you've just forgotten to add the quotes *in your question*.

Comment: so... is your code right? you don't close the `src`? you are missing a double quote at the end of each image! You should always validate -> http://validator.w3.org/ prior to ask why you get errors

Answer (score 5):

I suspect there might be a problem with your HTML, as you are missing quotes:

```
<img src="anImage.jpg />
```

Should be

```
<img src="anImage.jpg" />
```

Different browsers may handle this in different ways

For me, in Chorme, it certainly doesn't work in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/apKdC/, however when I fix the quotes in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/apKdC/1/ it all works fine.

Comment: I think he's just forgotten to keep the quotes as he changed his actual image `src`s to stuff like `anImage.jpg`. It doesn't alert `undefined` in any browser in the version without the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The *real* problem is that before version 9, Internet Explorer does not recognise unknown elements, such as the HTML5 elements you're using.

You can fix it by [including this](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) in your `<head>`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

For some background information, read: http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Here's a page that does just that, and works in IE6/7: http://jsbin.com/izina3

Answer (score 0):

you don't have correct html syntax see src attribute in first image missing "
http://jsfiddle.net/HwmEK/1/ see here its working

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally off-track here but shouldn't you have:

`alert($('img', $(this)).attr('src'));`

So **$(this)** not `this`